# AEM 6.x: How to access i18n translations via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, adobe, aem, translate

I'm trying to dynamically retrieve a translated message using Javascript from my created dictionary in AEM's translator (/libs/cq/i18n/translator.html).

We've got dictionary values set up like:

```
String          EN                  FR
========================================================
TEST-001        This is a Test1     FR:This is a Test1
TEST-002        This is a Test2     FR:This is a Test2
TEST-003        This is a Test3     FR:This is a Test3
```

I've looked through the Internationalizing UI Strings article (https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/components/i18n/i18n-dev.html) but when I try to the following:

```
Granite.I18n.setLocale("en");
Granite.I18n.get("TEST-001");
```

or

```
Granite.I18n.setLocale("fr");
Granite.I18n.get("TEST-001");
```

I only get returned the string I've passed in (i.e. "TEST-001").

Could someone help me understand how to retrieve the translated value back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where your translations are stored, you could try something like -

```
<script>
        Granite.I18n.init({
            locale: "<%= LocaleUtil.toRFC4646(request.getLocale()).toLowerCase() %>",
            urlPrefix: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/libs/cq/i18n/dict."
        });
    </script>
```

This is a sample taken from here -

```
/libs/cq/gui/components/projects/admin/page/head.jsp
```

Other way is

```
<html
    lang="<%= LocaleUtil.toRFC4646(request.getLocale()).toLowerCase() %>"
    data-i18n-dictionary-src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/libs/cq/i18n/dict.{+locale}.json">
```

taken from - `/libs/fd/fm/gui/components/admin/creationwizard/page/page.jsp`